# How to use Javadoc options (such as -notdeprecated) in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I would like to generate javadoc but excluding deprecated methods from it. I know there's an option called -notdeprecated (which does what I need) but I can't figure out how to specify this option.

To produce javadoc I go to Project->Generate Javadoc.
There I can choose between 'use standard doclet' and 'use custom doclet'.
I think I should use custom doclet to use options (am I wrong?). Now, where and how to specify the option?

I use eclipse 3.4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least on Eclipse 3.5, in the third page of the wizard, there is `Extra Javadoc options`.